# Drag Image in HTML5 Canvas with defined Boundaries

Tags: html, canvas, constraints, drag, bounds

I am working on HTML5 Canvas 2D, is there any function which can help to do like example given in below link -

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-bounds-tutorial-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link and code.
http://html5.litten.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-an-html5-canvas/

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
    <div>
    <canvas id="canvas5" height="300" width="400"> This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas. </canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas5;
    var ctx5;
    var x5 = 75;
    var y5 = 50;
    var dx5 = 5;
    var dy5 = 3;
    var WIDTH5 = 400;
    var HEIGHT5 = 300;
    var dragok = false;
    function rect(x,y,w,h) {
    ctx5.beginPath();
    ctx5.rect(x,y,w,h);
    ctx5.closePath();
    ctx5.fill();
    }
    function clear() {
    ctx5.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH5, HEIGHT5);
    }
    function init() {
    canvas5 = document.getElementById("canvas5");
    ctx5 = canvas5.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(draw5, 10);
    }
    function draw5() {
if(x5>10 && x5<350 && y5>10 && y5<350)
{
    clear();
    ctx5.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
    rect(0,0,WIDTH5,HEIGHT5);
    ctx5.fillStyle = "#444444";
    rect(x5 - 15, y5 - 15, 30, 30);
    }
    }
    function myMove(e){
    if (dragok){
    x5 = e.pageX - canvas5.offsetLeft;
    y5 = e.pageY - canvas5.offsetTop;
    }
    }
    function myDown(e){
    if (e.pageX < x5 + 15 + canvas5.offsetLeft)
    if (e.pageX > x5 - 15 + canvas5.offsetLeft)
    if (e.pageY < y5 + 15 + canvas5.offsetTop)
    if (e.pageY > y5 -15 + canvas5.offsetTop){
    x5 = e.pageX - canvas5.offsetLeft;
    y5 = e.pageY - canvas5.offsetTop;
    dragok = true;
    canvas5.onmousemove = myMove;
    }
    }
    function myUp(){
    dragok = false;
    canvas5.onmousemove = null;
    }
    init();
    canvas5.onmousedown = myDown;
    canvas5.onmouseup = myUp;
    </script>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Maneesh thanks, But I want something like given in image -

In Image, Hawk clipart is not moved out of the defined boundaries on Canvas 
Suppose we have fixed boundaries for Clipart starting at point (10,10) to (350,350) 
http://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/109906204570243538818/albums/5724543242938487617

Comment: You can do this applying the condition in draw5 function...if(x5>10 && x5<350 && y5>10 && y5<350)..edited the answer.

Comment: Ok Will do. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clean tutorial on how to make objects draggable inside an HTML5 Canvas I've written a tutorial with a lot of explanation [here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful).

For every object you create that is painted on the canvas you will probably want to also give it some kind of "limit bounds" such as limitX, limitY, limitWidth, limitHeight, etc. Then while you are dragging you need to make sure it remains within those bounds. If it is out of bounds you just force it to be on the closest side that it was attempted to be dragged out of.