# How to add image to canvas using fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to add images to canvas using fabric.js. I want to add a image every time the button is clicked. The image is stored in my computer. When the image is added to the canvas, I would like to be able to drag it over the canvas.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function addimage1() {
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
             var img = document.createElement("img");
             img.src = url_1;
             img.height = 50;
             img.width = 100;
             //optionally set a css class on the image
              // var class_name = "foo";
              // img.setAttribute("class", class_name);

              var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
              left: 100,
              top: 100,
              angle: 30,
              opacity: 0.85
              });
              canvas.add(imgInstance);
             //document.getElementById("resizable").appendChild(img);
              //document.body.appendChild(img);
            }
```

and here is the html code for button and canvas:

```
<div class="description">
<canvas id="c" width="710" height="600" style="background-color: #ffffff" ></canvas>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong so the image wont be displayed?

Comment: What's assigned to url_1?

Comment: sorry... var url_1 = '{% static "assets/img/stolovi/dva.png" %}';... the image that should be displayed.

Comment: Sorry I played with jQuery, and the canvas quite a bit but I have no idea what the "%" stands for in that line of yours...

Comment: it is how django is loading static files..
I figured out how to display the image, but i cannot move it around, can you help me with that?

Comment: Look at the answer in [Drag Image in HTML5 Canvas with defined Boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888107/drag-image-in-html5-canvas-with-defined-boundaries)